# How to turn a string into class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, enums

I have some error classes defined like so;

```
class CustomError implements IError {...}
class UnauthorizedError extends CustomError {...}
class NotFoundError extends CustomError {...}
class BadRequestError extends CustomError {...}
```

and an enum `Err` defined as follow;

```
enum Err {
      unauthorized = "UnauthorizedError",
      custom = "CustomError",
      notFound = "NotFoundError",
      badRequest = "BadRequestError",
}
```

how can i turn `Err.notFound` for example into the class `NotFoundError`.

Comment: You mean like `if (x == Err.custom) x = new CustomError()`?

Comment: @Bergi yes almost i want to create an instance using only the string without a switch case or if statment

Comment: But you need some kind of conditional. What should happen if `x` is not `Err.custom`?

Comment: @Bergi yes it will create an instance of the other class i have all those classes already defined `CustomError` is only an example)

Comment: You mean you have one class per enum value? You never mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Bergi yes exactly i'm sorry i just though it was clear

Comment: Nothing wrong with a `switch` statement actually. You need some way or another to list the eligible classes.